# Jetbrains YouTrack and Reporting

Tags: reporting, youtrack

I am working on a project using YouTrack for bug reporting. I would like to be able to build a few simple reports that come in handy during a stabilization period, reports that track trends like:

- The number of new bugs opened per day for the product (or for a feature).
- The number of of open bugs each day with a specific tag
- The fix rate per day

Has anybody had any success doing anything like this in YouTrack and if so where should I start looking?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use built in matrix reports for first and third cases. Just make a search request to get issues you are interested in and create report. One of the axis can be created date or resolved date. The only thing is that old dates are grouped.

If it's not enough you can use YouTrack [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/YTD3/General+REST+API) to get information you need.
You can start with [this](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/youtrack/2011/06/youtracksharp-a-net-client-for-youtrack/) or [this](http://hadihariri.com/2010/12/14/generating-graphs-for-youtrack-with-html-5-and-jquery/) thanks to Hadi Hariri.